# Cordova. Accessing Androids webView after onCreate function

Tags: cordova, webview, zooming, scaling

I'm building Cordova hybrid app with webView being scaled during onCreate execution. Everything works fine but after I set focus on **text input** scaling is being wasted. Tried increasing fonts size got same result. 
Next i thought that it's possible to repeat trick with scaling in native Java code so I created JavaScript interface that is being called after keyboards hide event(using ionic keyboard plugin). But i can't get webView and call most of it's methods after onCreate is completed and app is initialized as if i don't have pointer for right webView.

In my MainActivity.java code looks like this.

```
public class MainActivity extends CordovaActivity
{
    protected WebView wV;
    protected float ORIG_APP_W = 1080;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        loadUrl(launchUrl);
        wV = (WebView)this.appView.getEngine().getView();
        ...
        double globalScale = Math.ceil( ( width / ORIG_APP_W ) * 100 );
        wV.setInitialScale( (int)globalScale );
        wV.addJavascriptInterface(new MainActivity.Bridge(), "bridge");
    }

    class Bridge  extends CordovaPlugin {

        @JavascriptInterface
        public String refreshScaling()
        { 
            double globalScale = Math.ceil( ( width / ORIG_APP_W ) * 100);
            wV.setInitialScale( (int)globalScale );

            return "success";
        }
    }
```

And in JS

```
window.addEventListener('native.keyboardhide', onKeyboardHide);
...
    function onKeyboardHide(e){
     window.bridge.refreshScaling();
}
```